# Checking robot footprint for collision with the environment

Tags: ros, navigation, collision, nav-core, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to evaluate if a larger set of robot base poses (maybe 200-300) is in collision. More specifically, I would like to know if the robot footprint is in collision with the environment. I do not need to make a motion plan.

Has anyone done that before? I have been reading through the tutorials, especially those of the navigation stack but have not found anything suitable.

Right now, my best guess of how that could be accomplished is through adding a service to the move_base node in the navigation stack, as all required information is available there. However, I think this would mean changing a lot of the code (the move_base node, the base_global_planner interface in nav_core, etc.)

So if anyone has a suggestion for another or easier solution, please let me know.

Cheers,

Juergen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10966/checking-robot-footprint-for-collision-with-the-environment/) by [JuergenHess](https://answers.ros.org/users/370/juergenhess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2011-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `base_local_planner::CostmapModel` will help you do these footprint checks pretty easily. You can check out the documentation [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/base_local_planner/html/classbase__local__planner_1_1CostmapModel.html). Basically, you'll create the `CostmapModel` object by passing it a reference to a `costmap_2d::Costmap2D` object, and then call `footprintCost` on it. If the cost is negative, that footprint position is in collision with an object. I should also mention that this is the internal API of the navigation stack, so stability isn't guaranteed, but things haven't changed with that code in awhile so you should probably be OK.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2